# Change keybinding to show Unity Sidebar

Tags: 11.04, unity, taskbar

I tend to use the Super key in my keybindings (e.g. move between workspaces, vim commands, etc.) and holding the super key shows the sidebar. It's really annoying especially if I'm on the maximised window.
Is there a way to change this binding so that holding super doesn't show the sidebar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should install CompizConfig Settings Manager with the command:
    sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
Then, in Compiz, there is a Unity Plugin (look for the purple logo below). Under this section, it says "Key to show the luncher." Change it or disable it. Go nuts.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to have to separate buttons for showing the sidebar and activating the launcher?