# Can I bind the Unity dock to the Caps Lock key?

Tags: unity, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change keybinding to show Unity Sidebar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45523/change-keybinding-to-show-unity-sidebar)

So I really, really don't want to have to un-learn all of my "Win/Super" key bindings. And it occurred to me: there is one key on the keyboard that I *never* use: Caps Lock. Can I make Caps Lock do what Super does by default?

Note: I do **not** want to simply map Caps Lock to Super, because that would defeat the purpose of giving them two separate functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. Start CompizConfig Settings Manager, go to Ubuntu Unity Plugin and change the key under "Key to show the launcher". CompizConfig Settings Manager is available from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Thanks! Now I just need to figure out how to keep Caps Lock from actually turning on Caps Lock.

Comment: in the dash, search for 'keyboard', go to the layouts tab, then 'options': you can disable caps lock, or make it into another shift, or control key. However, I am not sure if it will still work as a shortcut for unity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can simply install CompizConfig and change the key for reveiling the launcher as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45523/change-keybinding-to-show-unity-sidebar).